# XSLT finding distinct combinations

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am beginner to xslt.  I want to find all unique combinations for Year, Month, Day, and Hour.

I have following xml file to transform:

```
<Plans>
    <Plan Name="Plan_1">
        <Book Name="Book_1">
            <Time Name="AAA">
                <Property Name="Year" Value="2001"/>
                <Property Name="Month" Value="01"/>
                <Property Name="Day" Value="10"/>
                <Property Name="Hour" Value="12"/>
            </Time>
            <Time Name="BBB">
                <Property Name="Year" Value="2001"/>
                <Property Name="Month" Value="01"/>
                <Property Name="Day" Value="10"/>
                <Property Name="Hour" Value="12"/>
            </Time>
            <Time Name="CCC">
                <Property Name="Year" Value="2004"/>
                <Property Name="Month" Value="02"/>
                <Property Name="Day" Value="11"/>
                <Property Name="Hour" Value="04"/>
            </Time>
            <Time Name="DDD">
                <Property Name="Year" Value="2004"/>
                <Property Name="Month" Value="03"/>
                <Property Name="Day" Value="20"/>
                <Property Name="Hour" Value="04"/>
            </Time>
        </Book>
        <Book Name="Book_22">
            <Time Name="CCC">
                <Property Name="Year" Value="2001"/>
                <Property Name="Month" Value="01"/>
                <Property Name="Day" Value="10"/>
                <Property Name="Hour" Value="12"/>
            </Time>
            <Time Name="DDD">
                <Property Name="Year" Value="2002"/>
                <Property Name="Month" Value="03"/>
                <Property Name="Day" Value="23"/>
                <Property Name="Hour" Value="03"/>
            </Time>
            <Time Name="EEE">
                <Property Name="Year" Value="2002"/>
                <Property Name="Month" Value="03"/>
                <Property Name="Day" Value="23"/>
                <Property Name="Hour" Value="03"/>
            </Time>
            <Time Name="FFF">
                <Property Name="Year" Value="2004"/>
                <Property Name="Month" Value="02"/>
                <Property Name="Day" Value="11"/>
                <Property Name="Hour" Value="04"/>
            </Time>
        </Book>
    </Plan>
</Plans>
```

Input xml has total eight total combinations (Four from each book).

I just want to know distinct combinations. So output should have 6 combinations because there are two same combinations.  The name of books does not matter.  I just want to see how many combinations there are.  And just label from 1 to the number...  It does not have to be in any order although it can be ordered by time...  If it is too hard to label numbers, then I just need to get distinct combinations only...

```
<Times>
    <Time Value="1">
        <Property Name="Year" Value="2001"/>
        <Property Name="Month" Value="01"/>
        <Property Name="Day" Value="10"/>
        <Property Name="Hour" Value="12"/>
    </Time>
    <Time Value="2">
        <Property Name="Year" Value="2004"/>
        <Property Name="Month" Value="02"/>
        <Property Name="Day" Value="11"/>
        <Property Name="Hour" Value="04"/>
    </Time>
    <Time Value="3">
        <Property Name="Year" Value="2004"/>
        <Property Name="Month" Value="03"/>
        <Property Name="Day" Value="20"/>
        <Property Name="Hour" Value="04"/>
    </Time>
    <Time Value="4">
        <Property Name="Year" Value="2001"/>
        <Property Name="Month" Value="01"/>
        <Property Name="Day" Value="10"/>
        <Property Name="Hour" Value="12"/>
    </Time>
    <Time Value="5">
        <Property Name="Year" Value="2002"/>
        <Property Name="Month" Value="03"/>
        <Property Name="Day" Value="23"/>
        <Property Name="Hour" Value="03"/>
    </Time>
</Times>
```

I tried to read for-each-group.  But I cannot make it work...  Does it have to be four loops or something since there are four porperties?  Please help me...

Comment: There can be multiple Plan.... Plan_1, Plan_2, etc...

Comment: You say the output should have 6 combinations, but your xml sample only shows 5! Also, in your output the combination 2001-01-10-12 is repeated twice. I think you only are expecting 4 combinations in this case...

Comment: You are correct. There should be 4 combinations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the other answers, you could also make use of **xsl:for-each-group** here.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select=".//Time" group-by="string-join(Property/@Value, '|')">
```

If your XSLT was using the Identity Template, you could then output the distinct **Time** elements within this group simply by doing this

```
 <Time Value="{position()}">
     <xsl:apply-templates />
 </Time>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <Times>
      <xsl:for-each-group select=".//Time" group-by="string-join(Property/@Value, '|')">
          <Time Value="{position()}">
              <xsl:apply-templates />
          </Time>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Times>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, you mention in comments (but not in the question) about having multiple **Plan** elements, but you have not said if you want to select distinct **Time** elements across all **Plan** elements, or have distinct elements for each separate **Plan**.

Suppose you did want to show distinct **Time** elements for each separate **Plan**, then just a small tweak will do. You would just effectively match the **Plan** element and have the grouping in that

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="Plan">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select=".//Time" group-by="string-join(Property/@Value, '|')">
          <Time Value="{position()}">
              <xsl:apply-templates />
          </Time>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do note these assume the order of your **Property** elements will always be the same ("Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour"). If not, you can get around this by doing the following

```
<xsl:for-each-group select=".//Time" group-by="concat(
     Property[@Name='Year']/@Value, '|', 
     Property[@Name='Month']/@Value, '|',
     Property[@Name='Day']/@Value, '|',
     Property[@Name='Hour']/@Value, '|')">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
distinct-values(/Times/Time/string-join(Property/@Value, '|'))
```

to get the distinct values. Then if necessary split them up into their component fields using tokenize().

Answer (score 1):

The following stylesheet builds upon the answer given by @Michael Kay. This is just to illustrate the solution and prove that it is working. Please accept *his* answer!

Numbering output elements is not hard, the easiest way is using `position()` in an attribute value template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/Plans">
      <Times>
         <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//Time/string-join(Property/@Value, '|'))">
            <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(.,'\|')"/>
            <Time Value="{position()}">
               <Property Name="Year" Value="{$tokens[1]}"/>
               <Property Name="Month" Value="{$tokens[2]}"/>
               <Property Name="Day" Value="{$tokens[3]}"/>
               <Property Name="Hour" Value="{$tokens[4]}"/>
            </Time>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </Times>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

As mentioned by @Tim C, you are probably expecting 4 result elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Times>
   <Time Value="1">
      <Property Name="Year" Value="2001"/>
      <Property Name="Month" Value="01"/>
      <Property Name="Day" Value="10"/>
      <Property Name="Hour" Value="12"/>
   </Time>
   <Time Value="2">
      <Property Name="Year" Value="2004"/>
      <Property Name="Month" Value="02"/>
      <Property Name="Day" Value="11"/>
      <Property Name="Hour" Value="04"/>
   </Time>
   <Time Value="3">
      <Property Name="Year" Value="2004"/>
      <Property Name="Month" Value="03"/>
      <Property Name="Day" Value="20"/>
      <Property Name="Hour" Value="04"/>
   </Time>
   <Time Value="4">
      <Property Name="Year" Value="2002"/>
      <Property Name="Month" Value="03"/>
      <Property Name="Day" Value="23"/>
      <Property Name="Hour" Value="03"/>
   </Time>
</Times>
```